# C++ memset - Extract size bytes and copy them to the supplied data address from buffer

Tags: c++, binary, char, memset

Is there an way to set the start position from an char pointer, which was an file in memory.

I need to read the extract size bytes of data from the stream, and copy them to the supplied data address and return the number of bytes read.
This was my memset tryout, i try to do someting like fread with an file in memory.
Hope someone can help me.

```
typedef signed   long long Int64; // osx for example

Int64 FileStream::read(void* data, Int64 size)
{
  // make sure, that size was not > as filename
  Int64 wanted_buffer = currentposition + size;
  if (wanted_buffer > memfile->GetSize())
    size = memfile->GetSize() - currentposition;

  // tryout with memcpy
  memcpy(data, currentposition + memfile->GetBuffer(), size);
  currentposition += size;    

  // like
  // return std::fread(data, 1, static_cast<std::size_t>(size), m_file);

  return currentposition;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use the c `FILE` struct you can use `fseek` on a `FILE *`.

Comment: yes, but this was exactly what i do not want not do. The file was completely in memory. I've tried it fread which works. Now i try something with memset, but i can not find any doc to get "bytes after start position".

Comment: Cast your `void *` to a `char *` and add a number to it. This moves your pointer in memory by an amount of bytes. If that's not what you need try writing your question a little differently; it's confusing.